# Android Firebase can update user email once only

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Currently i'm making user email and password update for my homework app. 
the problem is the Email can only be update ONCE. after that it just give information such as

```
D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
D/FirebaseApp: Notified 1 auth state listeners.
```

(there is no issue with updating password. only email)

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

// Get auth credentials from the user for re-authentication //User Sekarang punya email
AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(emailCurrent, passCurrent); // Current Login Credentials \\
// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
user.reauthenticate(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User re-authenticated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Now change your email address \\
                    //----------------Code for Changing Email Address----------\\
                    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    user.updateEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User email address updated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        System.out.println("Email Updated");
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    //----------------------------------------------------------\\
                } // End of isSuccessful
            } // End of onComplete
        });
```

Expected can update email unlimitedly.
Currently can only update email once.

Comment: Current workaround is by making the user login take data from firebase realtime database. However i would like to know if other are encountering the same issue when using firebase auth as their method of login

Comment: If take a look in the Firebase console, you see the old email after you perform the update?

Comment: yes i still see the old email

Comment: when i check in the old email there is an email from firebaseapp stating that "your sign-in email was changed" but this email was send only for the first time updating the email (1st email to 2nd email).. when requesting to update email again, there is no email send to the 2nd email stating the sign-in email was changed (2nd email to 3rd email).